# Dell Vostro screen flickering with pink color

Tags: 12.04, screen, monitor, flicker, dell-vostro

My laptop's screen started flickering, and I don't have a clue as to why this is happening. This Dell Vostro 2520 laptop came with Ubuntu 12.04 pre-installed.

[http://i.imgur.com/rru8xdg.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/rru8xdg.gifv)

Comment: That looks like a hardware issue. Check your cables.

Comment: Its a laptop. No cables except for power and external keyboard and mouse.

Comment: does it happen on Windows or another OS?

Comment: I'm using a separate laptop for Windows (typing on this). No.

Comment: @anjanesh doesn't happen on Windows on the same laptop? There are still ribbon cables inside that can come loose.

Comment: Oh I see. This Dell laptop came with Ubuntu 12..04 pre-loaded. I don't want to test this by installing Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely to be hardware related and one of the following

- The cable from videocard to screen which passes through the laptop hinge is faulty (damaged by repeated opening/closing of the screen) or loose.Close the screen to about 1cm and try to look at the screen,opening 1cm at a time until it gets back to the maximum screen opening.If the flicking stops at any position, it is probably an internal cable problem.
- The videocard could be faulty.This model seems to have HDMI and VGA out.Try attaching it to an external display and see if the flickering is present.
- The screen itself is faulty, since the flickering is pink and not white/dark it could be a circuit board attached to the screen rather than the backlight tube.